# Maple: How to convert Cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, maple

We get some expression in [Cylindrical coordinates (r, ϕ, z )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) like : `expr := r*z^2*sin((1/3)*`ϕ`)` we need to convert it into [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) and than back to Cylindrical coordinates. How to do such thing?

So I found something like this : `eval(expr, {r = sqrt(x^2+y^2), z = z,`ϕ`= arctan(y, x)})` but it seems incorrect, how to correct it and how make eval to convert backwords from Cartesian  to Cylindrical?

`&varphi;` == ϕ

So I try:

```
R := 1; 

H := h; 

sigma[0] := sig0;

sigma := sigma[0]*z^2*sin((1/3)*`&varphi;`);

toCar := eval(sigma, {r = sqrt(x^2+y^2), z = z, `&varphi;` = arctan(y, x)});

toCyl := collect(eval(toCar, {x = r*cos(`&varphi;`), y = r*sin(`&varphi;`), z = z}), `&varphi;`)
```

It looks close to true but look: [image]

why `arctan(r*sin(`ϕ`), r*cos(`ϕ`))` is not shown as ϕ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak Maple, but it looks like your eval takes you from Cartesian to cylindrical coordinates.  The inverse is $x=r \cos \phi , y=r \sin \phi, z=z$.  The Wikipedia link you have gives this, though using $\rho$ instead of $r$

Comment: Please see post update...

Comment: Seems to me that $\arctan\left(\frac{r\sin\phi}{r\cos\phi}\right)$ should evaluate to $\phi$, but that is Maple, not math